# How to find definition of type in C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm trying to cross-compile qt5webengine under buildroot but there are some compilation errors.

```
output/build/qt5webengine-5.6.1-1/src/core/delegated_frame_node.cpp: In function void QtWebEngineCore::waitChromiumSync(gfx::TransferableFence*):
output/build/qt5webengine-5.6.1-1/src/core/delegated_frame_node.cpp:202:16: error: PFNEGLCLIENTWAITSYNCKHRPROC does not name a type static PFNEGLCLIENTWAITSYNCKHRPROC eglClientWaitSyncKHR = 0;
output/build/qt5webengine-5.6.1-1/src/core/delegated_frame_node.cpp:207:41: error: PFNEGLCLIENTWAITSYNCKHRPROC was not declared in this scope
```

I tried to find the definition of PFNEGLCLIENTWAITSYNCKHRPROC and I found only following typedef:

```
typedef EGLint (EGLAPIENTRYP PFNEGLCLIENTWAITSYNCKHRPROC) (EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSyncKHR sync, EGLint flags, EGLTimeKHR timeout);
```

To be honest I'm not sure how to interprete it. Is that declaration of type of pointer to function?

Anyone can explain that?

Second question - if this is not the definition of type PFNEGLCLIENTWAITSYNCKHRPROC - how to find out where is the right definition? I'm trying to compile it under Linux and this qt5webengine uses gcc/g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: This defines PFNEGLCLIENTWAITSYNCKHRPROC to be a type of a *function*, not of a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Just after a little search on internet, I have found that qt framework has cross-compile issue for webengine component but they have closed/fixed their issue in 18 Mar '16 7:47 AM. So u may look your Qt version and update if it needs.

You can look in their bug report pages: [webengine cannot be built on TI hardware](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52809)